# Filter a sorted list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, filter

I have a list in which elements are already sorted.
I want to filter out elements that are greater than a given number.

For example,

```
original_list = [2,3,5,7,11]
limit = 6
expected_list = [2,3,5] # All elements <=6
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

All the existing questions I saw, deal with unsorted lists. 
I believe there will be a more efficient way of filtering if the list is already sorted.

Comment: 5 is on mid element, you can define mid element `mid = len(original_list)\\2` and next define like x = original_list[:mid]

Comment: @M3duZa but what if it's not? What if the `limit` is `8`?

Comment: @M3duZa The list is already sorted you don't need to traverse till last element every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are 2 approaches:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

# using a while loop
def gen(l, m):
    i = 0
    while i < len(l) and l[i] <= m:
        yield l[i]
        i += 1

original_list = [2,3,5,7,11]
limit = 6

print(list(gen(original_list, limit)))

# using bisect_right
limit = bisect_right(original_list, limit)
print(original_list[:limit])
```

output:

```
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
```

overall bisect perform much better since the time complexity is O(logN), using the `while` loop version will give you O(N) time complexity, but sometimes the `while` loop version can be more efficient if your `limit` is in the very lower part of your list

Comment: how come? when you compute big O you take in account the worst case scenario

Comment: well if you want at this level of details, but usually you don't,  but for the `while` loop is O(N) since worst-case scenario will be if `limit = N`

Comment: the bisect  algorithm is a binary search so it is O(logN) , you can have a look  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022249/what-is-the-complexity-of-bisect-algorithm

Comment: I agree about that but that it is not including in the `while` loop solution

Answer (score 9):

```
import bisect

original_list = [2,3,5,7,11]
limit = 6
expected_list = [2,3,5] # All elements <=6

index = bisect.bisect(original_list, limit)
filtered = original_list[:index]
assert filtered == expected_list
```

Answer (score 3):

If your list is sorted in ascending order and you want value below certain threshold you might use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) following way:

```
import itertools
original_list = [2,3,5,7,11]
limit = 6
expected_list = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x:x<=limit, original_list))
print(expected_list)  # [2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

can we use list comprehension here,

```
expected_list = [value for value in original_list if value < limit]
```

Comment: The OP asked for the most efficient way for sorted arrays. As you solution will iterate over all values in the list, this solution is not the way to go here.